# How to set the color of an icon in Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have this, which I would assume to work, but doesn't:

```html
<mat-icon color="white">home</mat-icon>
```

Then, I also have:

```html
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" type="submit"
 [disabled]="!recipientForm.form.valid">
    <mat-icon color="white">save</mat-icon>SAVE
</button>
```

This code snippet, for some reason, does work (shows the icon as white).

How do I get the lone `mat-icon` to show up as white *using* the `color` attribute? (I can easily just add a white class, but I want to understand this)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

That's because the `color` input only accepts three attributes: `"primary"`, `"accent"` or `"warn"`. Hence, you'll have to style the icons the CSS way:

1. Add a class to style your icon:

   ```css
   .white-icon {
       color: white;
   }
   /* Note: If you're using an SVG icon, you should make the class target the `<svg>` element */
   .white-icon svg {
       fill: white;
   }
   ```
2. Add the class to your icon:

   ```html
   <mat-icon class="white-icon">menu</mat-icon>
   ```

Comment: That must be correct, but why would it work if embedded under a Material button?

Comment: Maybe because it inherits the color? It uses `fill: currentColor;` after all.

Comment: how will it work if i have 2 themes in styles.scss? can the color be different of the icon based on which theme i pick at runtime?

Comment: @Vik SCSS has nested classes

Comment: if your SVG has styled defined inside you will have to remove them. eg. the style `.a` is often applied which will take precedence over this. Be sure to remove the `class='a'` and not just the `a { fill: ... }` attribute

Comment: also I'd never heard of 'currentColor' which is used by mat-icon https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/ (you can actually use color: white instead of fill: white when you have stripped the classes)

Comment: My <mat-icon> was inside a <button mat-raised-button> and so I had to use the !important tag after color for it to work. Like so: `<button mat-raised-button color="primary"><mat-icon style="color: white !important">edit</mat-icon></button>`

Comment: If I have an object say myObj and it has a field say isActive and I just want to render the color="warn" or color="primary" how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 21):

In the component.css or app.css add Icon Color styles

```css
.material-icons.color_green { color: #00FF00; }
.material-icons.color_white { color: #FFFFFF; }
```

In the component.html set the icon class

```xml
<mat-icon class="material-icons color_green">games</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="material-icons color_white">cloud</mat-icon>
```

ng build

Comment: this is a much more simple way to do the job. I thought it was a kind of selector at first, thanks to your answer I've figured it out

Answer (score 18):

Or simply

add to your element

`[ngStyle]="{'color': myVariableColor}"`

eg

`<mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color': myVariableColor}">{{ getActivityIcon() }}</mat-icon>`

Where `color` can be defined at another component etc

Comment: Avoid using functions inside of .html files, it's bad practice. More informations here - https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16

Comment: @sgracki are you going to comment to every answer on SO about why not use those methods?

Comment: yes, of course. Currently i am building team of senior angular developers that will improve overall quality of answers here.

Comment: what does this have todo with my answer about the color change? @sgracki 
Also what you are doing, commenting out of scope I dont think it follows the community standards. Good luck building your team and gettings views on your blog. I have reported this behaviour.

Comment: no offence :) Just saying it's not a good practice using functions inside .html files. Keep calm and code on! Best regards!

Comment: Pretty sure ngStyle was made for this

Answer (score 9):

`color="white"` is not a known attribute to Angular Material.

color attribute can changed to `primary`, `accent`, and `warn`. as said in this [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#theming)

your icon inside button works because its parent class button has css class of `color:white`, or may be your `color="accent"` is white. check the developer tools to find it.

By default, icons will use the current font color

Answer (score 5):

```
<mat-icon style="-webkit-text-fill-color:blue">face</mat-icon>
```

Comment: Add some description

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, Here is the explanation.

You cannot add HTML colors(red, white, green) to `color` directive directly.
You are only allowed to add (primary, accent, and warn).

> What this `color` directive does is add classes to the element based
> on the given value

e.g:

```html
<mat-icon color="primary">home</mat-icon> <!-- this will add (.mat-primary) class -->
<mat-icon color="accent">home</mat-icon> <!-- this will add (.mat-accent) class -->
<mat-icon color="warn">home</mat-icon> <!-- this will add (.mat-warn) class -->
```

Now, these classes contains css `color` property.

```css
//This comes from material theming
.mat-primary {
 color: #3f51b5;
}
```

See what [color](https://www.materialpalette.com/colors) - [built-in theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme) has for these (mat-primary, mat-accent, mat-warn).

So if you want to change the color globally for every material component, Then [create your own custom palette](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#custom-themes-with-sass)

If you just want to change for a single element then follow *sfanjoy's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632037/11719787)

Answer (score 0):

Since for some reason white isn't available for selection, I have found that `mat-palette($mat-grey, 50)` was close enough to white, for my needs at least.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a move that I'm using to set the color dynamically, it defaults to primary theme if the variable is undefined.

in your component define your color

```
  /**Sets the button colors - Defaults to primary them color */
  @Input('buttonsColor') _buttonsColor: string
```

in your style (sass here) - this forces the icon to use the color of it's container

```
.mat-custom{
  .mat-icon, .mat-icon-button{
     color:inherit !important;
  }  
}
```

in your html surround your button with a div

```
        <div [class.mat-custom]="!!_buttonsColor" [style.color]="_buttonsColor"> 
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="doSomething()">
                <mat-icon [svgIcon]="'refresh'" color="primary"></mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
```