# How to use the primary color on a non-mat element in Angular Material app?

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I found plenty of guides talking about how to define your own theme of Angular Material. But all I want is to use the `primary color' of the current theme on a normal HTML element.

Something like:

```
<div style="color: primary-color">OK</div>
```

I do not want to go through the hell to define a palette and color variable. I just want to get the value which Angular uses.

Comment: ```<button md-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>```

Comment: @fatemefazli...my bad. The `button` is a special element. I meant a general element, like a **div** tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the color of an icon in Angular Material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46812064/how-to-set-the-color-of-an-icon-in-angular-material)

Comment: @tom, all those posts are talking about how to define a custom `primary` color. But I want to **get** the current primary color...I think it is very different.

Comment: @davidshen84 Because you say 'set', I didn't think you wan't to *get* but *set*. To do so you would simply do this: `<mat-icon color="primary">menu</mat-icon>`

Comment: I am not using `mat-icon`. I am using a normal HTML element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these two bugs, the document was not accurate. The latest version of the [document](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#note-using-the-code-mat-color-code-function-to-extract-colors-from-a-palette) works for me.

- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13476
- https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5152

Answer (score -2):

You don't need a custom palette but you will need a custom theme and variables to do this. Angular Material provides a sass function to extract colour from a theme but for that to happen the theme has to be a sass theme, you can't do it with the pre-compiled themes as they are in static css:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@include mat-core();
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo);
$app-accent : mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$app-warn : mat-palette($mat-red);
$app-theme: mat-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($app-theme);

.custom-class {
  color: mat-color($app-primary);
}
```

and in the HTML view:

```
<div class="custom-class">OK</div>
```

Edit: You can do it with a pre-built theme but you will have to go through a similar amount of steps as above. But the above leaves you with the flexibility of changing colours as you see fit.

https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: Yes, I have seen that post. But I **don't** want to define a new primary color. I want to use **the primary color** of the current theme.

Comment: if you don't define a theme, how do you get the `$app-them` variable?

Comment: Follow the link